# Showing the count of my user and display it on badge. (Codeigniter)

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-query-builder

Newbie here. I did an ajax to count the users and display it on my badge, however, whenever I'm clicking on 1 button (Modal with table), it is displaying on all badges. For example. I have 4 users in my first row modal table. The #4 count is displayed to all of my badges. Which is something that is weird. My target is to display the count in my badge dynamically. I have provided a video and images below for better explanation.

https://streamable.com/z6dqgi << This is the output of what I made. (Look at the badge count behaviour)

**This is what I aim/target for.**
[image]

**View:**

```
<div class="tab-content" id="custom-tabs-two-tabContent">
              
              <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="custom-tabs-two-all" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="custom-tabs-two-all-tab">
                     <table class="table">
                            <thead class="">
                                <tr>
                                <th scope="col"><i class="fas fa-hashtag"></i></th>
                                <th scope="col"><i class="fas fa-mobile-alt mr-2"></i>UUID</th>
                                <th scope="col">Full Name</th>
                                 <th scope="col"><i class="fas fa-envelope-open-text mr-2"></i>Email</th>
                                <th scope="col"><i class="fas fa-phone-alt mr-2"></i>Contact Number</th>
                                <th scope="col"><i class="fas fa-at mr-2"></i>Username</th>
                                <th scope="col">Level</th>
                                <th scope="col">balance</th>
                                <th scope="col">&emsp;&emsp;&nbsp;Actions</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                
                               <?php 
                               foreach($result as $rows) {   $uuid = $rows->uuid;
                               $userID = $rows->userID; ?>     
                                   <?php if($rows->uuid===$_SESSION['uid']): ?>     
                                <tr>
                                <th><?php echo $rows->userID;  ?></th>
                                <td><?php echo $rows->uuid; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $rows->firstname; ?>&nbsp;<?php echo $rows->lastname; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $rows->email; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $rows->mobile; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $rows->username; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $rows->account_type; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $rows->currentPoints; ?></td>
                                <td>
                                   
                                        <button data-id="<?php echo $rows->userID; ?>" class=" fundTable btn btn-success btn-sm text-bold " type="button"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#fundModal">
                                            <i class="fas fa-hand-holding-usd mr-1"></i> <?php echo $rows->userID; ?>FUND
                                        </button>
                                        
                                        
                                        <button data-id="<?php echo $rows->userID; ?>" class=" allTable btn btn-danger btn-sm text-bold" type="button"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal">
                                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-users"></i>
                                            <span data-id="<?php echo $rows->userID; ?>" class="badge badge-warning navbar-badge"></span>
                                            
                                        </button>   
                                 
                                        
                                        
                                
                                        
                               </td>
                               </tr>
                                     <?php else: ?>
                                                  
                                            <?php endif;?>
                                     <?php } ?>
                            </tbody>
                     </table>
   </div>

<span class="badge badge-warning navbar-badge">2</span>  //this is where the total value should be displayed.                                           
</button>
```

**Model:**

```
public function view($userID = 0){
            $this->db->select("*");
            $this->db->from("users");
            $this->db->where( "uuid=".$userID);
            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $result = $query->result();
            
        }
```

**Controller:**

```
public function view()
    {
        
        if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
            $view_id = $this->input->post('view_id');
            
            if ($post = $this->networks->view($view_id)) {
                $data = array('responce' => 'success', 'post' => $post);
              
            } else {
                $data = array('responce' => 'error', 'message' => 'failed to fetch record');
            }
            echo json_encode($data);
        } else {
            echo "No direct script access allowed";
          
        }
        
    }
```

**Script:**

```
<script>


          $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".allTable").on("click", function(){
        var view_id = $(this).data('id')
    
        $.ajax({
         
           url: "<?=site_url('network/view')?>",

          type: "post",
          dataType: "json",
          data: {
            view_id: view_id  
          },
            success: function(data){
              
              var tbody ="";
              var item =data.post; 


            for(var key in item) {
                    tbody +="<tr>";
                    tbody += "<td>"+item[key].userID+"</td>";
                    tbody += "<td>"+item[key].uuid+"</td>";
                    tbody += "<td>"+item[key].firstname+" "+item[key].lastname+"</td>";
                    tbody += "<td>"+item[key].email+"</td>";
                    tbody += "<td>"+item[key].mobile+"</td>";
                    tbody += "<td>"+item[key].username+"</td>";
                    tbody +="</tr>"
                                 }
           $(".navbar-badge").text(Object.keys(item).length); 
          $(".tbody").html(tbody);
          $('#editModal').modal('show');
            }
     
        });
        })
        });
 
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, can you show your html table ?

Comment: Hello, done adding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have use `.navbar-badge` this will target all elements which has that class that's the reason its changing all span tags. Instead , as you are already getting `data-id` of button you can use this to target only required span using `$("span[data-id=" + view_id + "]").text("sometext")` .

***Demo code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".allTable").on("click", function() {
    var view_id = $(this).data('id')

    /*$.ajax({
//somecodes of ajx ..
      */
    // $("span[data-id="+view_id+"]").text(Object.keys(item).length);
    $("span[data-id=" + view_id + "]").text(10);
    // other codes ..
    /*  }
    });*/
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css">

<table class="table">
  <thead class="">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col"><i class="fas fa-hashtag"></i></th>
      <th scope="col"><i class="fas fa-mobile-alt mr-2"></i>UUID</th>
      <th scope="col">Full Name</th>
      <th scope="col"><i class="fas fa-envelope-open-text mr-2"></i>Email</th>
      <th scope="col"><i class="fas fa-phone-alt mr-2"></i>Contact Number</th>
      <th scope="col"><i class="fas fa-at mr-2"></i>Username</th>
      <th scope="col">Level</th>
      <th scope="col">balance</th>
      <th scope="col">&emsp;&emsp;&nbsp;Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>
        1
      </th>
      <td>
        123
      </td>
      <td>
        abc
      </td>
      <td>
        a@gmail.com
      </td>
      <td>
        12213
      </td>

      <td>

        <button data-id="1" class=" fundTable btn btn-success btn-sm text-bold " type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#fundModal">
                                            <i class="fas fa-hand-holding-usd mr-1"></i> FUND
                                        </button>


        <button data-id="1" class=" allTable btn btn-danger btn-sm text-bold" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal">
                                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-users"></i>
                                            <span data-id="1" class="badge badge-warning navbar-badge"></span>
                                            
                                        </button>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        2
      </th>
      <td>
        1232
      </td>
      <td>
        abc2
      </td>
      <td>
        a2@gmail.com
      </td>
      <td>
        12213
      </td>

      <td>

        <button data-id="2" class=" fundTable btn btn-success btn-sm text-bold " type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#fundModal">
                                            <i class="fas fa-hand-holding-usd mr-2"></i> FUND
                                        </button>


        <button data-id="2" class=" allTable btn btn-danger btn-sm text-bold" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal">
                                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-users"></i>
                                            <span data-id="2" class="badge badge-warning navbar-badge"></span>
                                            
                                        </button>

      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is working. However, my target is, when the page is visited. The count in badge is automatically visible. Your solution can only be seen after clicking the table. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, your current code provided is showing that part after click event . where is code to display them on page visited ? Also you didn't mention this in your asked question.

Comment: Yes. That was my bad. However. I'll still check this as an answer. And make another post about my main target. Your solution is really helpful. Thank you.